# Can we categorize the result of View Result tree listener in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am logging in with multiple users simultaneously and performing some tasks. I have used `View Result tree` listener to store the results.

How can I see the result of each login and other scripts per user?

For example, the `View Result tree` listener is showing the result for login 1 to Login n, and showing the same result for each script. I want to see the result in the form login 1 and script 1, login 2 and script 2, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) as postfix for your Sampler label like:

`Login${__threadNum}`

This way you will be able to distinguish results coming from different virtual users, for example:

- For 1st virtual user sampler label would be `Login1`
- For 2nd virtual user sampler label would be `Login2`
- etc.

Demo:

[image: JMeter Threadnum function use case]

Going forward you can also add current [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) loop number if your test plan assumes > 1 loop. It can be done via [__iterationNum() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#iterationNumsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-1-font-sup) available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/). You can install it as a part of `Custom JMeter Functions` bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: Custom JMeter Functions JMeter Plugins Manager]